# Euler summation problem

Tags: trigonometry, summation

A post in physics stack exchange led me to get confused in one of the steps where the summation of a Euler form suddenly became a trigonometric expression. The answer to the post I got confused in was:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/470315/how-to-derive-the-intensity-formula-of-a-diffraction-grating?

In the answer (there is only one answer to the linked post), there is a summation which I do not get the result it yields. I do get one should use geometric series to approach it, and I can get the numerator expression (due to there being $2N+1$ terms), but I am having trouble seeing the denominator expression.

$$\sum_{n=-N}^Ne^{iknd\sin \theta}=\frac{\sin\big((N+\frac{1}{2})kd\sin\theta\big)}{\sin\big(\frac{1}{2}kd\sin\theta\big)}$$

Could anyone help me show how the above is proved? Thank you

**Edit:** attached is my working out but I do not know what to do  with $e^{i\phi}$ term.
[image]

[image]

Comment: In this form it is easier to note that LHS is $1$ plus a sum of $2\cos {knd sin\theta}$ by grouping conjugate terms together and then multiplying with the denominator and using basic trigonometric formulas gets you a telescopic sum - try work it out as this computation appears often (you can first change variables $x=\sin \theta$) to make it clearer

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for the suggestion. Letting $\phi=kd\sin\theta$ I have posted an image of my workings,  but I almost have the expression but I seem to have trouble analyzing the $e^{i\phi}$ portion. I would appreciate the help from here.

Comment: $e^{-iN\phi}\frac{e^{\frac{i(2N+1)\phi}{2}}}{e^{i\phi}}=1$ actually, not $e^{i\phi}$ so you are good

Comment: Man I am so dumb, thank you very much !!!!

Comment: No problem and happy to help